# Create a formula for finding minimum value

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a problem to choose a value which minimizes the delay from a set of delays. Let's assume I have n nodes in which each node has a delay value. The problem formulation is as follows:

$min(x_1^1D_1;x_2^1D_2;x_3^1D_3;...;x_n^1D_n)$.

How to write that problem into a single form in math so I do not need to write all indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More compactly,$$\min_{i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}}x_i^1D_i$$

Comment: Thank you, that is what I want